# Starting of Tomcat Instance from Jenkins

Tags: shell, tomcat, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, multiple-instances

I installed multiple instances of Tomcat in my Ubuntu machine. I was trying to start Tomcat (one of the instances from multiple Tomcat instances) from Jenkins. Jenkins is showing that Tomcat started. But Tomcat is still in shutdown state only.

Answer (score 0):

In jenkins, When an build completes all the process Id's which are involved in the build are getting killed.

So mentioning BUILD_ID=dontKillMe ./home/tomcat/startup.sh in Execute shell script make it possible.